# Flutter: how to combine Card widgets in a ListView

Tags: flutter

I have a screen which is displaying data from a web service via JSON. The data is displayed within a ListView with each item in a card.

This is working great, but if I have 2 items on the same date, I'd like to display them together under the same date.

The first image is how it displays now, and the second is a mock up of what I'd like. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Cheers,

Paul

JSON:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "JOBID":23,
         "START_DATE":1588809600000,
         "START_TIME":"08:35",
         "END_TIME":"17:35",
         "JOB_NAME":"Fence repair"
      },
      {
         "JOBID":24,
         "START_DATE":1588809600000,
         "START_TIME":"18:00",
         "END_TIME":"07:30",
         "JOB_NAME":""
      },
      {
         "JOBID":25,
         "START_DATE":1588896000000,
         "START_TIME":"08:35",
         "END_TIME":"17:35",
         "JOB_NAME":"Fence repair"
      }
   ]
}
```

[image: This is the current display]

[image: This is how I'd like it to display]

Comment: You should be prepare list as per you requirement from webservice json.

Comment: Please share you dummy json data so i will make  other list data as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks @NikhilVadoliya. I have added the JSON into my question. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I have added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be implement below way

First you should add List of child in your data model

For Example :

```
class DataModel {
  int JOBID;
  int START_DATE;
  String START_TIME;
  String END_TIME;
  String JOB_NAME;
  List<DataModel> child;

  DataModel(this.JOBID, this.START_DATE, this.START_TIME, this.END_TIME,
      this.JOB_NAME, this.child);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "{JobID:$JOBID,StartDate:${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(START_DATE)},StartTime:$START_TIME,EndTime:$END_TIME,JobName:$JOB_NAME,child:${child.toString()}}";
  }
}
```

Now you add below two method which filter data and provide list with child of same date

```
  List<DataModel> getFilteredList(ListData listData) {
    listData.rows.sort((a, b) =>
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(b.START_DATE)
            .compareTo(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(a.START_DATE)));

    for (int i = 0; i < listData.rows.length; i++) {
      print(listData.rows[i].toString());
    }
    DataModel prev;
    bool isHeader = false;
    List<DataModel> filterList = [];
    int index = 0;
    listData.rows.forEach((element) {
      if (prev != null && !isSameDate(element.START_DATE, prev.START_DATE)) {
        isHeader = true;
      }
      if (!isHeader) {
        if (filterList.length != 0) {
          filterList[index].child.add(element);
        } else {
          filterList.add(DataModel(element.JOBID, element.START_DATE,
              element.START_TIME, element.END_TIME, element.JOB_NAME, []));
        }
      } else {
        filterList.add(DataModel(element.JOBID, element.START_DATE,
            element.START_TIME, element.END_TIME, element.JOB_NAME, []));
        index++;
        isHeader = false;
      }
      prev = element;
    });
    return filterList;
  }

  bool isSameDate(int startDate, int startDate2) {
    var date1 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startDate);
    var date2 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startDate2);
    return date1.day == date2.day &&
        date1.month == date2.month &&
        date1.year == date2.year;
  }




filteredListData = getFilteredList(listData);
```

fileredListData have proper data

Full Example

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  ListData listData = ListData.empty();

  List<DataModel> filteredListData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listData.rows = [];
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(23, 1588809600000, "08:35", "17:35", "F-1", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(24, 1588809600000, "18:00", "07:30", "F-1.1", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(25, 1588896000000, "08:35", "17:35", "A-1", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(26, 1590057927000, "08:35", "17:35", "New -1", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(27, 1588896000000, "08:35", "17:35", "A-1.1", []));
    listData.rows.add(
        new DataModel(28, 1590057927000, "08:35", "17:35", "New -1.1", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(29, 1588896000000, "08:35", "17:35", "A-1.2", []));

    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(30, 1590056427000, "08:35", "17:35", "New-1.2", []));
    listData.rows
        .add(new DataModel(31, 1590057027000, "08:35", "17:35", "New-1.3", []));

    filteredListData = getFilteredList(listData);
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredListData.length; i++) {
      print(filteredListData[i].toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: filteredListData.length,
      itemBuilder: (builder, parentIndex) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                "${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(filteredListData[parentIndex].START_DATE).toString()} - ${filteredListData[parentIndex].JOB_NAME}"),
            if (filteredListData[parentIndex].child.length > 0)
              ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
                  return Text(
                      filteredListData[parentIndex].child[index].JOB_NAME);
                },
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: filteredListData[parentIndex].child.length,
              )
          ],
        );
      },
    ));
  }

  List<DataModel> getFilteredList(ListData listData) {
    listData.rows.sort((a, b) =>
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(b.START_DATE)
            .compareTo(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(a.START_DATE)));

    for (int i = 0; i < listData.rows.length; i++) {
      print(listData.rows[i].toString());
    }
    DataModel prev;
    bool isHeader = false;
    List<DataModel> filterList = [];
    int index = 0;
    listData.rows.forEach((element) {
      if (prev != null && !isSameDate(element.START_DATE, prev.START_DATE)) {
        isHeader = true;
      }
      if (!isHeader) {
        if (filterList.length != 0) {
          filterList[index].child.add(element);
        } else {
          filterList.add(DataModel(element.JOBID, element.START_DATE,
              element.START_TIME, element.END_TIME, element.JOB_NAME, []));
        }
      } else {
        filterList.add(DataModel(element.JOBID, element.START_DATE,
            element.START_TIME, element.END_TIME, element.JOB_NAME, []));
        index++;
        isHeader = false;
      }
      prev = element;
    });
    return filterList;
  }

  bool isSameDate(int startDate, int startDate2) {
    var date1 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startDate);
    var date2 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startDate2);
    return date1.day == date2.day &&
        date1.month == date2.month &&
        date1.year == date2.year;
  }
}
```

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, brilliant. I really appreciate the amount of time you put into answering my question. Have a great day.

Comment: Welcome @PaulCoshott.